# How to connect to my RDS instance with a Angular application deployed on an EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently recreating my website in Angular with NodeJS.

I have an EC2 instance with Nginx which serves the angular application. I now want to allow the user to get data from my rds instance (After they have logged in/ are authenticated)
I have nodejs installed on the instance as well.

I am wondering what the best practice is, to with communicate with my RDS instance securely/ other AWS services. I was thinking to create a service component in my project and install the AWS sdk and use the service component to communicate. But I really want to know what the best practice is. I have come from a PHP background so this is fairly new to me.

Comment: This is a bit broad but generally you'd use S3 to serve the Angular part and a server in the middle to communicate with other things like RDS.  That's a traditional service oriented architecture (SOA).  There are lots of variations like serving the Angular from the server as you're doing.  Again, this is a big question ultimately.  Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi @stdunbar, thanks for your comment. I think currently I may looking into hosting the angular application on my EC2 instance, and then utilise Lambda functions to get users data etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would say depending on the type of RDS you are running , you would install required framework to connect to that type of database within your app and just use RDS information like endpoint, user name , pass to connect to database ( there is also an option to use integrated IAM auth).

That leaves also open the subject how security around your RDS/ec2 is configured ( so I.e. if it allows connection to that specific port etc )

Hope this gives you some idea where to start.